# R does not Recognize that a Package is Installed

Tags: r, package

When I try to use the command `library(Seurat)`, I get an error telling me "there is no package called ‘pillar’" installed.  However, I **do** have the pillar package installed: I've checked my packages folder multiple times.  The full text of the error is:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘pillar’

Furthermore, I've tried downloading pillar again via the command `devtools::install_github("r-lib/pillar")`, but that doesn't seem to work either.  This may be because, every time I try this, it returns the message:

```
installing the source package ‘pillar’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 113884 bytes (111 KB)

==================================================
downloaded 111 KB

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34:  1816 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
      1817 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --no-echo --args ${args}

**Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status**

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/r8/9lw5sbl5549_bw2qlv3y24580000gn/T/Rtmpa5vp68/downloaded_packages’
```

**Any help resolving this issue would be immensely appreciated.  Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What happens if you run `library(pillar)`? Does it load? `pillar` is also available on CRAN now so you should just be able to do `install.packages("pillar")`. Unless you need the dev version for some reason? It seems like there should be more to that installation error message. Normally there is a specific message about what went wrong.

Comment: @MrFlick, `library(pillar)` returns the same error message about pillar not being installed.  I've tried `install.packages("pillar")` multiple times: that's how I installed it originally.  Also, I added the full error message to my original post, I hope that helps clarify things!

Comment: Your problem, right now, is that the `pillar` package did not / does not install.  As it is needed by `Seurat` you have a problem.  You need to figure why it fails.

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? These messages sound like you are running R 4.0 on a version older than 10.13 which is the minimal requirement. You either need to use an older version of R or update your OS.

Comment: @MrFlick, Many thanks for your assistance.  I'm indeed running MacOS 10.12.6, so I'll fix that ASAP.  I'll let you know if that takes care of the issue.  You've been a huge help, I really appreciate it.